# Working on a calculator in java and taking the values as String

Tags: java

like "1+23"

parse to double for example.. then calculate..

but when  i have a decimal the program crashes  for example "1.1+2"  the program glitches on the 1.1  when i'm parsing it

```
 if(s.contains("+"))

    {
        int n = s.indexOf("+");




        String w1 = s.substring(0,n);

        String w2 = s.substring(n+1,s.length());

        part1= (long) Double.parseDouble(w1);
        part2 = (long)Double.parseDouble(w2);
```

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1.1"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:48)

Comment: help yourself first by providing us with the needed info: we need at least a code sample and the stacktrace of the exception. crashing can be caused by a million things.

Comment: You are not providing enough information.  How does it "glitch"?  Where is the stacktrace? What does your code look like?

Comment: Why are you parsing it as a double and casting it to a long?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why are you casting from a double to long? that will result in your number being truncated. in the case of 1.1 you will get 1. What you should do is use the following:

```
Float.parseFloat(w1);
```

where w1 is your floating point value.

you cannot have part1 be a long value, since long values cannot hold floating points. part1 must be a float.

Answer (score 2):

You *probably* use `Integer.parseInt()`. If that's **not** the case, then you need to specify *a lot* more detail (**how** does it crash, post the stack trace, post the code).

You need to switch to *either* floating point numbers (`Double.parseDouble()`) *or* to [`BigDecimal`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) ([`new BigDecimal()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal%28java.lang.String%29)).